# Hathway ISP - Cable Modem - Connection Failure

Tags: networking, internet, modem

India has an ISP named Hathway which provides connection through cable modems. The cable modem is connected through a CAT6 cable to the computer.

It is surprising that while MS Windows is able to connect with the internet and get to the page named login.hathway.com, for accessing the internet, Ubuntu fails to even procure the IP as a DSL connection. Attempt to connection with DHCP based setting have also failed.

I have also tried using `sudo pppoeconf` and it fails to detect the DSL modem and the connection therein.

Any clues on this mystery?

Comment: I too have "cable" internet but not from Hathway and it works for both MS Win and Ubuntu (dual boot). It connects to my laptop via a telephone plug. There's no modem at least that I know of. Under "Connection Information" _General_ of network manager, I have "Interface: Ethernet (eth0)", my MAC address, "Driver: sky2", Speed: 100 Mb/s. And under _IPv4_ I have various things but under _IPv6_ there's just "Ignored". I don't know if that's of any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I studied how Hathway connects to the Internet by using a redirection on http://login.hathway.com. Apparently there is a redirection script, which redirects the browser to one of the following addresses:

1. 203.212.193.59
2. 203.212.193.60
3. 203.212.193.61

Now, typing these IP addresses in the browser's address bar does not seem to work as well. What works is the following:

```
IP.AD.DR.ES/bsp/startportal.do?CPURL=http://login.hathway.com
```

where `IP.AD.DR.ES` is any one of the above IPs.

Answer (score 0):

Yup i am also a Hathway(Bangalore) user and was facing the same issue. Try the following IP addresses to get to the login page. See if this works, as it works just fine for me :

```
http://203.212.193.59
http://203.212.193.60
http://203.212.193.61
```

Comment: Could you increase some more information in the answer? For example connection type DSL --> PPOE ---> username --> password --> service name etc.?

Comment: I have tried the above IPs and they do not seem to be recognised. What I found from the Windows command prompt is that the IP assigned and the gateway are in some range of 116.X.X.X. I also found that sudo `pppoeconf` does not seem to detect the modems!